# Configuration of Rspec terminal output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am a beginner with `Rspec`, and I found out my terminal output like this.

[image]
It's really in a mess and hard to understand test result.

Unlike the output in official tutorial.
[image]

Should I install some tools or modify some configuration?

**Update**

**zombie.rb**

```
class Zombie
attr_accessor :name
    def initialize
        @name = 'Error_Ash'
    end
end
```

**zombie_spec.rb**

```
require "spec_helper"
require "zombie"

#give Class
describe Zombie do 

# example 
    it "is named Class_Ash"
    zombie = Zombie.new 
    zombie.name.should == "Ash"
end
```

**error msg**

```
Coda:rspec_pra Coda$ rspec spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb --format doc
/Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-support-3.4.1/lib/rspec/support.rb:87:in `block in <module:Support>': expected: "Ash" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
     got: "Error_Ash" (using ==)
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-support-3.4.1/lib/rspec/support.rb:96:in `call'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-support-3.4.1/lib/rspec/support.rb:96:in `notify_failure'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-expectations-3.4.0/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:27:in `fail_with'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-expectations-3.4.0/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/operators.rb:71:in `fail_with_message'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-expectations-3.4.0/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/operators.rb:106:in `__delegate_operator'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-expectations-3.4.0/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/operators.rb:91:in `eval_match'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-expectations-3.4.0/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/operators.rb:51:in `block in use_custom_matcher_or_delegate'
    from /Users/Coda/Desktop/code/ruby_pra/rspec_pra/spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:385:in `module_exec'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:385:in `subclass'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:255:in `block in define_example_group_method'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:43:in `block in expose_example_group_alias'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in expose_example_group_alias_globally'
    from /Users/Coda/Desktop/code/ruby_pra/rspec_pra/spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `load'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:106:in `setup'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/bin/rspec:22:in `load'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/bin/rspec:22:in `<main>'
Coda:rspec_pra Coda$
```

Comment: rspec is failing because of a syntax error in zombie_spec.rb at line 12 (uninitialized constant). It does not reach the point where the --format switch would give you the nice output :)
EDIT: If you post the complete error output, and the spec code, we might be able to fix that ;)

Comment: I modify some code and repost the first picture, and I've put code on it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hm, not sure if that is related, but the `something.should == ` notation is deprecated. You should use use `expect(zombie.name).to eq "Ash"` instead.
And the it block is missing the do ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is nothing in your spec_helper that somehow overrides the --format switch (which I do not even know if it's possible) then this should give you readable tests that pass:

**zombie.rb** exactly as you posted,

**zombie_spec**

```
require "spec_helper"
require "zombie"

describe Zombie do 
  it "is named Ash" do
    zombie = Zombie.new 
    expect(zombie.name).to eq "Ash"
  end
end
```

and command `rspec spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb -f d` which is short for `--format documentation`

EDIT*: Oh sorry, the Error you posted is indeed an RSpec error... Its just not formated, as you said x.x
try the --tty flag maybe?
`rspec spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb --tty -f d`

Comment: It seems that I miss that block. I add `do`&`end`, and it works. But I should really modify it to `expect`. Thanks.